# Custom Google map markerClusterer Markers not clustering

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-markers

I have a custom Google map with several markers or 'locations' on it that is perfectly operational on a Wordpress site (6.1.1). I am trying to have the locations cluster but I am not able to get it to work. I added an empty array for 'markers' as stated in the Google docs to my javascript but still no clustering;

```
// Create empty array of Markers
  const markers = [];
```

I have no errors in the console. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have read all I can find but I can't find a solution. The map works just as intended except that the locations will not cluster.

Here is my javascript file in its entirety;

```
//CUSTOM GOOGLE MAP
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 53.41291, lng: -7.94389 },
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,

    styles: [
      {
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#ffffff",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: "off",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#616161",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#f5f5f5",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative.land_parcel",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: "off",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative.land_parcel",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#bdbdbd",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#ffffff",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels.text",
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: "off",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#757575",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.business",
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: "off",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#e5e5e5",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "labels.text",
        stylers: [
          {
            visibility: "off",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#9e9e9e",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#e5e5e5",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#757575",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#dadada",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{}],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.local",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#616161",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.local",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#9e9e9e",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit.line",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#e5e5e5",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit.station",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#eeeeee",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#526b81",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [
          {
            color: "#526b81",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  const locations = [
    [
      "<h3>Arthaus Hotel Dublin</h3> <p>Mercer Street Lower<br/>Dublin 2<br/>Ireland<br/>D02 TW61</p>",
      53.339552834177255,
      -6.264078911187995,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/arthaus-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Clontarf Castle Hotel</h3> <p>Castle Ave<br/>Clontarf<br/>Dublin 3<br/>Ireland<br/>D03 W5N0</p>",
      53.364754,
      -6.206846,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/clontarf-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>The Clybaun Hotel</h3> <p>Clybaun Road<br/>Knocknacarra<br/>Co. Galway<br/>Ireland<br/>H91 F62V</p>",
      53.26948,
      -9.108403,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/clybaun-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Crowne Plaza Dublin Airport</h3> <p>Park Northwood<br/>Santry<br/>Dublin 9<br/>Ireland<br/>D09 X9X2</p>",
      53.404402,
      -6.245599,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/crowneplaza-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Crowne Plaza Dublin - Blanchardstown</h3> <p>The Blanchardstown Centre<br/>Dublin 15<br/>Ireland<br/>D15 T1FD</p>",
      53.395652,
      -6.389966,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/crowneplaza-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Crowne Plaza Dundalk</h3> <p>Inner Relief Road<br/>Dundalk<br/>Co. Louth<br/>Ireland<br/>A91 EF88</p>",
      53.9803991,
      -6.3906617,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/crowneplaza-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Hard Rock Dublin Hotel</h3> <p>18 Exchange Street Upper<br/>Dublin 2<br/>Ireland<br/>D08 AV24</p>",
      53.344286,
      -6.268025,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/hardrock-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>The Hendrick Smithfield</h3> <p>6 – 11 Hendrick Street<br/>Dublin 7<br/>Ireland<br/>D07 KX28</p>",
      53.347805,
      -6.280856,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/the-hendrick-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Holiday Inn Express Dublin Airport</h3> <p>Northwood Park<br/>NorthWood<br/>Dublin 9<br/>Ireland<br/>D09 RY17</p>",
      53.404275,
      -6.244526,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/holiday-express-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Innisfallen Hotel</h3> <p>Fossa<br/>Killarney<br/>Co. Kerry<br/>Ireland<br/>V93 CR90</p>",
      52.070643,
      -9.573754,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/innisfallen-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Hotel Killarney</h3> <p>Cork Road<br/>Killarney<br/>Ireland<br/>V93 FX00</p>",
      52.060288,
      -9.484677,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/killarney-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Kinsale Hotel & Spa</h3> <p>Rathmore, Kinsale, County Cork, P17 F542</p>",
      51.698865,
      -8.465479,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/kinsale-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Waterford Hotel</h3> <p>N25 Cork Road<br/>Waterford<br/>Co. Waterford<br/>Ireland<br/>X91 YV04</p>",
      52.24843,
      -7.12148,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Limerick Ennis Road Hotel</h3> <p>Coonagh Roundabout<br/>Ennis Road<br/>N18<br/>Limerick<br/>Ireland<br/>V94 R990</p>",
      52.673351,
      -8.675873,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Limerick Castletroy Hotel</h3> <p>Park Point<br/>Castletroy<br/>Dublin Road<br/>Limerick<br/>Ireland<br/>V94 Y83C</p>",
      52.66458,
      -8.585064,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Galway City Hotel</h3> <p>Joyce Roundabout<br/>Galway City Centre<br/>Tuam Road Galway<br/>Ireland<br/>H91 HX8Y</p>",
      53.282843,
      -9.036276,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Dublin Phoenix Park Hotel</h3> <p>Auburn Avenue Roundabout<br/>Navan Road<br/>Dublin 15<br/>Ireland<br/>D15 EW29</p>",
      53.380359,
      -6.355205,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Dublin City Centre Rathmines</h3> <p>Rathmines Road<br/>Dublin 6<br/>Ireland<br/>D06 HF30</p>",
      53.325093,
      -6.265007,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Plus Dublin City Centre</h3> <p>44 Townsend St<br/>Dublin 2<br/>Ireland<br/>D02 DY01</p>",
      53.346,
      -6.25204,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Dublin Airport South Hotel</h3> <p>Shangan Road<br/>Ballymun<br/>Dublin 9<br/>Ireland<br/>D09 W8H7</p>",
      53.396499,
      -6.26321,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Dublin Airport North Swords Hotel</h3> <p>Pinnock Hill Roundabout<br/>Swords<br/>Co. Dublin<br/>Ireland<br/>K67 K6R2</p>",
      53.449318,
      -6.223605,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Cork Airport Hotel</h3> <p>Black Ash<br/>Kinsale Road Roundabout<br/>Frankfield Road<br/>Co. Cork<br/>Ireland<br/>T12 E2XY</p>",
      51.872464,
      -8.470073,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
    [
      "<h3>Travelodge Belfast Central Hotel</h3> <p>15 Brunswick Street<br/>Belfast<br/>Belfast<br/>United Kingdom<br/>BT2 7GE</p>",
      54.595178,
      -5.933368,
      "/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/img/map/travelodge-map-marker.svg",
      33,
      51,
    ],
  ];

  // Create empty array of Markers
  const markers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    const currMarker = locations[i];

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: currMarker[1], lng: currMarker[2] },
      map,
      title: currMarker[0],
      icon: {
        url: currMarker[3],
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(currMarker[4], currMarker[5]),
      },
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map,
    });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: currMarker[0],
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    marker.addListener("click", () => {
      infoWindow.setContent(label);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }

  /// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath:
      "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
  });
}
// LOCATION
//53.34619001916453, -6.251790086266539
```

Here are the javascript files I am loading via the functions.php file into the footer. First ;

```
///Google Clusterer
<script src="http://tifcohotels.local/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/js/vendor/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js?ver=6.1.1" id="google-cluster-script-js"></script>

///My Custom Map script
<script src="http://tifcohotels.local/wp-content/themes/tifcohotels-child/assets/js/maps-v2.js?ver=6.1.1" id="google-custom-script-js"></script>

///Google Map ID
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCG5WJQky4XmaL4mx4Idc6iH58VyYd98xg&amp;callback=initMap" id="google-map-script-js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue here was my solution:

In my js file:

```
    // Create empty array of Markers
  const markers = [];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
  // const markers = new Array();

  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    const currMarker = locations[i];

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: currMarker[1], lng: currMarker[2] },
      map,
      title: currMarker[0],
      icon: {
        url: currMarker[3],
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(currMarker[4], currMarker[5]),
      },
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map,
    });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: currMarker[0],
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
    
    marker.addListener('mouseout', function(marker, i) { infowindow.close(); });
  }

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
}
```